# How to fix leak_tracker errors on Flutter compilation

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, compilation

I'm experiencing errors recently with trying to compile my Flutter app. It seems the problem is related to the firebase_core package which seems to depend on the leak_tracker and leak_tracker_testing packages.

When I depend on the firebase_core package it doesn't matter which version I select, I get the following errors:

```
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker_testing-2.0.3/lib/src/leak_testing.dart:146:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'notGCed'.
        notGCed: ignoredLeaks.notGCed.merge(
        ^^^^^^^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker-10.0.4/lib/src/leak_tracking/primitives/model.dart:130:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const IgnoredLeaks({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker_testing-2.0.3/lib/src/leak_testing.dart:193:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'notGCed'.
        notGCed: newNotGCed,
        ^^^^^^^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/leak_tracker-10.0.4/lib/src/leak_tracking/primitives/model.dart:130:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const IgnoredLeaks({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried reinstalling the SDK and upgrading it but nothing seems to fix the issue. I'm lost in trying to find the solution.

Please help me out!

Comment: the issue is that you have two packages with conflict version that depends on each other, my issue resolved when I fix the version of some packages in pubspec.yaml, a git history can reveal what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appeared to be in both the Firebase packages in combination with flutter 3.9.0 SDK.

After updating the Firebase packages and the Flutter SDK to 3.9.1 the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have two packages with conflict version that depends on each other. Can be the packages from flutter sdk or the packages installed on pubspec.yaml. Verify your packages.

I've the same issue after I ran "flutter update-packages --force-upgrade", probably one of the updated packages conflited with any other already installed. For me it solve by reinstalling the flutter and dart sdk.

These are the steps that I followed:

1. First I did all the steps in Uninstall page from flutter (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/uninstall?tab=windows)
2. Reinstall your flutter sdk according with your configuration (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install)
3. Run "flutter doctor" in terminal and solve the issues

I hope this could help someone.